# How can i make payment application using the blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapps, dapp-development, payments

i want to make payment based application by scratch using blockchain, so where can i learn from scratch and what are the different component that i should learn to make an application or a website solely?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too broad, because Ethereum is a smart contract platform and payments can be handled by contracts.

If you just want to learn ethereum development I would advice to checkout [cryptozombies](https://cryptozombies.io) to get started into coding in a fun way.

Cheers